# I would like to know more about designing broad bandwidth transformers and current baluns using binocular cores

Tags: impedance-matching, balun, transmission-line, choke-balun

Internet pickings seem mighty slim, would appreciate links to books, articles or websites.

If there are good "how to" items that explain the design, that too.  Thanks and 73s

Answer (score 1):

The best reference is from Jim Brown, K9YC.

http://audiosystemsgroup.com/RFI-Ham.pdf is a well-respected and accurate reference.

Check out the documents available at http://k9yc.com/publish.htm and https://audiosystemsgroup.com.

*Low Band DXing* by John Devoldere, ON4UN has a chapter that contains information about binocular core transformers. Available from the ARRL.

https://www.w8ji.com/core_selection.htm

[Here's a page I wrote about broadband binocular core transformers years ago.](https://web.archive.org/web/20181115070846/http://www.w0btu.com/Beverage_antennas.html#Beverage_Antenna_Transformers)